# An error occurred the last time AutoSSL ran

Tags: outlook, ssl-certificate, bluehost

I have got a sudden issue in my mail server in bluehost.

> An error occurred the last time AutoSSL ran

Some of the web-mails went down, while some others are going without any issue.
For the web-mails that shown send-receive error, i changed the port numbers to default and is working.

What can I do for removing the SSL error ?

Answer (score 1):

As I enquired with the mail server support, i came to know my ip has been bnlocked by my ISP. and contacted the ISP.

To chechk about IP block ,goto
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a78.101.172.172&run=toolpage
and enter your ip.

there is a drop down button near the ip text box for more options other than checking blacklist.